MikTeX: Discrepancies in files between two installed instances of the same version
Two years ago, I installed a MikTeX 21.6 2 distribution. I'm trying to keep a baseline of my working environment and it is the reason why I don't want to upgrade a running system if there is no benefit.
Yesterday, my colleague tried to install the same MikTeX distribution version like mine (21.6 2) but when he compiled, he run into an error and we discovered with the \listfiles command that almost all files are identicals except some few ones (e.g. in our case the colortbl.sty file).
My understanding from a distribution approach is that normally the basic setup should remain identical over the time for one given version.
My question:

Why is it possible that some files are modified after the publication of one MikTeX distribution?


As far as I know package versions in MikTeX has nothing to do with the version numbers of the packages. The version number refers to the MikTeX infrastructure.

is colortbl part of the basic setup or was it installed on the fly? (I have no idea, I always install a full miktex and keep it up-to-date.)

one of the main features of miktex as opposed to texlive is that it updates/installs packages on the fly as required by a document, so getting different versions at different times is quite expected

@UlrikeFischer, thanks for the pragmatic workaround. I'm considering improving my infrastructure by performing regular updates and running non-regression testing, so that I can maintain an operational setup with an identified configuration.

@DavidCarlisle, thanks for the information. I'm considering updating my infrastructure to also work with RHEL (currently using MikTeX on Windows). I might take this opportunity to evaluate the suitability of TeXLive. If it doesn't download the current version on the fly, it might simplify configuration management for me.
